# Siebel 'like' operation in calculated value

Tags: siebel

I need to set up the calculated value, for a field in SR BC. I need to check the current login name of the user. So if the users are other than kr0001,kr0002 etc, it should perform some other operation

My expression for the calculated value:

```
IIF(LoginName() = "kr0001", "Y", "")
```

How can I modify this to achieve the above?
Can I use '%like%' operation here?

Answer (score 1):

You still use the equals operator, but use the asterisk for the wildcards.

```
IIF(LoginName() = "*r00*", "Y", "")
```

Comment: Can I use not equal within this expression?
IIF(LoginName() != "*r00*", "Y", "") 

Is it valid?

Comment: Use <> instead of != in calculated fields